# Blower motor turns on by itself

Tags: hvac

I have Goodman model # GPG1348090M41AA. Back in December the blower motor ran constantly. I'd pull the breaker to shut it off, & when I turn the breaker back on, the blower motor would start right back. I clean the burners & reset the flame rollout switch. I thought that fixed it.

First time i turn A/C it worked fine. When it cut off after reaching the temp, I noticed the blower fan was running. I cut it off at breaker and a couple of days later, I kicked breaker back on with out the blower motor coming on. I had it cut off at the Thermostat a few days later when i noticed the blower motor running. since the cooled normally I just cut the breaker until i needed it to cool. A lock out code was the only code couple days ago. I tinkered with it trying to get the motor to run with no luck. I was about to call a pro, when tonight I happen to notice it running. so I turned it on to cool the house, & the A/C work perfect. when A/C reached it's cut off temp, it shut off but the blower motor had been running.

Comment: It may be the thermostat. If it is battery powered, change the battery. How old is the thermostat?

Comment: Are you sure someone didn't accidentally set the switch on the thermostat to "Fan = On" instead of "Fan = Auto"?

Comment: Sorry,  I should have included what i have tested. Though the fan has in the past, slipped into the "ON" without me knowing. However this time it was in the Auto . lol I did test thermostat, That wasn't it. I finally realized the when the red light is not on at all is actually a code. A code to replace the control board. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Older thermostats have a "Fan" switch that works independently of the system's On/Off switch.  That switch should be on *Auto*, not *On* or *Circ* or any other setting.

Newer thermostats have fan control too but some don't have a separate switch, just a setting somewhere.  Find it.  Make sure it's on *Auto*. Some newer thermostats have additional hidden "installer" settings that control the fan and limit what the user can do.  You can access those settings if you know how.

A thermostat can be wired incorrectly so the fan is always on.

The air handler can be wired incorrectly so the fan is always on.

**Is it the thermostat?**

If there is a fan switch, turn it to Auto (not On).  Did that fix it?  Good.

If it's on auto:  Turn off the breaker to the system.  Remove the thermostat from the wall.  Make note of how all the wires are connected to it.   Are any two wires connected to the same terminal?  That might be the problem.  Post a picture of that, and of the other end of this cable at the air handler.  If no two wires are on the same terminal, disconnect all the wires.  No wire should be touching the thermostat or any other wire or anything at all.  Turn the power back on.  Is the fan running?  If not, the thermostat is the problem.  If the fan is still running the problem is at the air handler.  Turn the breaker back off and put everything back. (You made note of where the wires were, right?)

Some thermostats are held to a base by plastic clips and can be yanked off the wall.  If you know you have one of these you can run the above test without turning off the power or disconnecting wires just by pulling the thermostat off the wall.  As long as you see that, on the base, no two wires are attached to the same terminal.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included what i have tested. Though the fan has in the past, slipped into the "ON" without me knowing. However this time it was in the Auto . lol I did test thermostat, That wasn't it. I finally realized the when the red light is not on at all is actually a code. A code to replace the control board. Thanks for your help

Comment: On an old furnace the FAN/OFF/AUTO switch may be labelled SUMMER FAN.

Answer (score 0):

Many AC systems have an option to keep the blower on continuously. The idea is even if it isn't actively heating/cooling the air it helps circulate the air to avoid hot/cold spots. I have never heard of one that randomly turns on and off. Do you have either multiple thermostats or a smart thermostat? I could imagine they might want to turn the blower on and off even if it wasn't actively heating / cooling the house.

Comment: Thanks. I have neither of those thermostats.  I finally realized that when the red light is not on at all, it is actually a code. A code to replace the control board. Thanks for your help